# TypeORM not creating table when starting

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, express, typeorm

I just started using typescript, and have been trying to learn how to use TypeORM on the backend.

I started coding a CRUD API using typeORM and postgreSQL, after I made all the initial setup configuration I ran the application, but the TypeORM is not creating my User entity on the database.

Here is what my code looks like:

- data-source.ts file:

> import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'; 
> import { DataSource } from "typeorm"
> import { User } from "./entity/User"
>
> dotenv.config();
>
> export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
> type: "postgres",
> host: process.env.TYPEORM_HOST,
> port: 5432,
> username: process.env.TYPEORM_USER,
> password: process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD,
> database: process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE,
> logging: false,
> entities: [User],
> migrations: [],
> subscribers: [],
> synchronize: true,
> });

- app.ts file:

> import express from 'express';
> import { AppDataSource } from "./db/data-source";
>
> class App {
> public express: express.Application
>
> public constructor() {
> this.express = express();
> this.middlewares();
> this.routes();
> this.datababase();
> };
>
> private middlewares(): void {
> this.express.use(express.json());
> };
>
> private routes(): void {
> this.express.get('/teste', (_req, res) => res.send('api rodando'));
> };
>
> private async datababase(): Promise {
> await AppDataSource.initialize().then(async () => console.log('connected')).catch(error => console.log(error.message));
> };
> }
>
> export default new App().express;

- my User.ts entity file (PS: the import is obviously part of
  the file but the stack overflow editor straight up refuses to place it inside the code
  block no matter what I do):

{
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column } from "typeorm"

```
@Entity('users')
export class User {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column()
    firstName: string

    @Column()
    lastName: string

    @Column()
    email: string

    @Column()
    password: string
};
```

I expected that by the moment I ran the application the User table would be created automatically since I passed the tag synchronize on the data-source.ts file, and referenced the User entity as well. But nothing happens when I run the application.

Note that the "connected" message shows up on my console when the `initialize` method is called at the `database` method in my App class, which indicates to me that the initialization is working fine.

PS: I apologize for the inconsistence of the code blocks, but I really can't figure out the stack overflow text editor, I am absolutely NEVER able to make this thing work properly.

Answer (score -1):

Please try `@Entity({name: "users"})` instead of `@Entity('users')`

You can optionally use these other options `@Entity({name: "users", schema: "public", synchronize: true})`